# django user profile database problem

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have app called aaa and in models.py in aaa i have sth like:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BBB(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    newsletter=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I add to my setting.py

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'aaa.BBB'
```

then i go to django shell and type

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> a=User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> a.get_profile()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 373, in get_profile
    self._profile_cache = model._default_manager.using(self._state.db).get(user__id__exact=self.id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.2.5-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/query.py", line 347, in get
    % self.model._meta.object_name)
DoesNotExist: BBB matching query does not exist.
```

Some body have idea what is wrong?
Edit: I do manage.py syncdb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

> The method get_profile() does not
>   create the profile, if it does not
>   exist. You need to register a handler
>   for the signal
>   django.db.models.signals.post_save on
>   the User model, and, in the handler,
>   if created=True, create the associated
>   user profile.

The signal they mention is not really documented django-style where they provide code examples, so I will create an example for you:

```
from django.db.models import signals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def create_userprofile(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created'] # object created or just saved?

    if created:
        BBB.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])  # instance is the user
        # create a BBB "profile" for your user upon creation.
        # now every time a user is created, a BBB profile will exist too.
        # user.BBB or user.get_profile() will always return something

signals.post_save.connect(create_userprofile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for help. I have still one question this code I should put in my views.py where I try to call user.get_profile()?

Comment: Place it below the BBB model, since the signal handler is immediately concerned with it. If your `models.py` module is too crowded or you like to keep your app components separated, you can put this in a `signals.py` module in the same app (sort of an unspoken rule).

Answer (score 1):

That's ok, everything works. `DoesNotExist: BBB matching query does not exist.` means *there is no BBB (user profile) for this user (matching query, i.e. get me the user profile for this user)*.

Use the `DoesNotExist` exception to assert whether a particular user has an associated user profile. When you create a `BBB` instance which is related to user `a`, you won't get a `DoesNotExist` exception.